# Is Sentinel-2 measuring absorbance or reflectance?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have just started playing around with the Google Earth Engine and I was wondering whether the values recorded (shown in picture below), are supposed to represent the reflectance or absorbance of that specific band? Moreover, is the higher value in Band 4 saying that the pixel is more red or less red?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These are the two Sentinel-2 data sets on GEE with all the information that you require

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR

Both dataset represents reflectance values, the L1C product represents top of atmosphere reflectance and the L2A product represents atmospherically corrected surface reflectance values.
Therefore, if there is a higher value in Band 4, it means the pixel is more red yes.